# Scattering Matrix of a Given Circuit - Microwave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, scattering, s-matrix-theory

This might be an easy question but I couldn't find it in our course book[Microwave Engineering, Pozar, 4th ed] or on internet.

I have a homework and one of the questions asks me to find the S-Matrix of a given circuit. Circuit is like this. [Above and bottom stuff are irrelevant. They bound to other questions of hw. Also, yeap, my handwriting is bad.]

[image]

If the circuit doesn't have those $l_1$ and $l_2$ lengths, I know what to do** but when those two lengths come in, I don't exactly know how they will affect my result. 
I assume they will add some phase shift like $e^{j{\beta}l}$ or something like that but I am not sure about it.

Overall my question is, if the S-Matrix of a circuit without lengths is $[S^{'}]$ = $[S_{11}^{'} ,S_{12}^{'}, S_{21}^{'}, S_{22}^{'}]$, what will be the resulting S-matrix when they are added?

**: To find $S_{11}$ & $S_{21}$, match right part with $Z_0$ (to make $V_2^+ = 0$) and calculate stuff. Also to find $S_{12}$ & $S_{22}$ match left part with $Z_0$ (to make $V_1^+ = 0$) and calculate stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A length of lossless matched transmission line has the s-matrix

$$S = \left[\begin{matrix}
            0 & e^{-j\beta{}l} \\
            e^{-j\beta{}l} & 0
            \end{matrix}\right]$$

So now you have three parts whose s-matrices you know: a transmission line on the "input" side, the lumped element network in the middle, and a transmission line on the output side.

Unfortunately, finding the equivalent s-matrix of a cascaded combination of two-ports is not as easy as you'd hope it to be.

The usual way to do it is to

1. Convert each of your 2-ports to T-parameters: 
   $$ T_{11}=\frac{\det(S)}{S_{21}} $$
   $$ T_{12}=\frac{S_{11}}{S_{21}}$$
   $$ T_{21}=\frac{-S_{22}}{S_{21}}$$
   $$ T_{22}=\frac{1}{S_{21}}$$
2. Find the t-matrix of the combination. This is the easy part that makes the other steps worthwhile:
   $$T_{eq}=T_A T_B T_C$$
3. Convert back to S-parameters. 
   $$S_{11}=\frac{T_{12}}{T_{22}}$$
   $$S_{12}=\frac{\det(T)}{T_{22}}$$
   $$S_{21}=\frac{1}{T_{22}}$$
   $$S_{22}=\frac{-T_{21}}{T_{22}}$$